# CSJS addCallback always runs SSJS

Tags: xpages

Can someone please shed some light on why this CSJS code is always running my SSJS code regardless of the CSJS seeming to return true or false?

CSJS code

```
message = "Starting Settle ATM Process..."
$(".infoMessage").text(message);
atmID = $("input.atmID").val(); //pull from hidden input

var deferred = atmRPC.closeATMFirstSettle();
deferred.addCallback(function(result){
    if (result == "false") {
        alert("Close command failed during 1st Settle ATM process. System will retry...");
        var insideDeferred = atmMRPC.closeATMSecondSettle();
        insideDeferred.addCallback(function(result) {
            if (result == "false") {
                message = "Close command failed during Settle ATM process. Please try again later."
                $(".infoMessage").text(message);
                atmRPC.updateInfoMsg(message);
                return false;
            } else if(result == "true"){
                var deferred = atmRPC.settleATMFirst();
                deferred.addCallback(function(result){
                    if (result == "false") {
                        alert("Settlement failed during 1st attempt. System will retry...");
                        var insideDeferred = atmMRPC.settleATMSecond();
                        insideDeferred.addCallback(function(result) {
                            if (result == "false") {
                                message = "Settlement failed. Please try again later."
                                $(".infoMessage").text(message);
                                atmRPC.updateInfoMsg(message);
                                return false;
                            } else if(result == "true"){
                                message = atmID + " has been successfully Settled."
                                $(".infoMessage").text(message);
                                atmRPC.updateInfoMsg(message);
//                              return true;
                            }
                        })
                    } else if(result == "true"){
                        message = atmID + " has been successfully Settled."
                        $(".infoMessage").text(message); 
                        atmRPC.updateInfoMsg(message);
//                      return true;
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    } else if(result == "true"){
        var deferred = atmRPC.settleATMFirst();
        deferred.addCallback(function(result){
            if (result == "false") {
                alert("Settlement failed during 1st attempt. System will retry...");
                var insideDeferred = atmMRPC.settleATMSecond();
                insideDeferred.addCallback(function(result) {
                    if (result == "false") {
                        alert("Settlement failed during 1st attempt. System will retry...");
                        message = "Settlement failed. Please try again later."
                        $(".infoMessage").text(message);
                        atmRPC.updateInfoMsg(message);
                        return false;
                    } else if(result == "true"){
                        message = atmID + " has been successfully Settled."
                        $(".infoMessage").text(message);
                        atmRPC.updateInfoMsg(message);
//                      return true;
                    }
                })
            } else if(result == "true"){
                message = atmID + " has been successfully Settled."
                $(".infoMessage").text(message);
                atmRPC.updateInfoMsg(message);
//              return true;
            }
        })
    }
  })
```

closeATMFirsSettle and closeATMSecondSettle are identical with exception of the boolean variable

```
if(atmBean.atmStatus == "OPEN" || atmBean.atmStatus == "WOUNDED") {
    var firstTry:boolean = atmBean.closeATM(atmBean.atmID, userBean.userID);
    return firstTry.toString();
} else if(atmBean.atmStatus == "CLOSED") {
    return "true";
} else {
    return "false";
}
```

settleATMFirst and settleATMSecond are identical with exception of the boolean variable

```
sessionScope.infoMsg = null;
try {
    if(atmBean.atmAmountReceived == null) {
        var settleAmt:Integer = Integer.parseInt(atmBean.atmTodaySettlementAmt);
    } else {
        var settleAmt:Integer = Integer.parseInt(atmBean.atmAmountReceived);
    }
} catch(e) {
    message:String = "1st Settle ATM Amount Error: " + e;
    logInfo(message);
    return sessionScope.infoMsg = message;
}
var firstTry:boolean = atmBean.settleATM(atmBean.atmID, userBean.userID, settleAmt);
return firstTry.toString();
```

atmBean.settleATM

```
public boolean settleATM(String atmId, String employeeId, Integer settlementAmount, String attempt){
    //This method called by RPC control from client JS
    AtmOperationSettlementResult result = null;
    boolean returnValue = false;

    try {
        result = AtmTerminalUtil.settleAtm(atmID, employeeId, settlementAmount);
        returnValue = result.getSuccess();
        if(attempt.equals("Second")) {
            System.out.println("ATM Bean - Second Attempt");
            if(!returnValue) {
                handleATMError(result);
            }
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    //saveATMHistory();
    return returnValue;  //return status of operation to UI
}
```

I know the SSJS in the Server tab is always being ran because the log entries show the value of a viewScope that is set if the atmBean.settleATM returns a false.

Sorry, didn't realize until the last comment that everyone may be thinking the SSJS code I'm talking about is in the RPC, but I'm referring to the Server tab.

Comment: Can you explain what is going on. How is the SSJS code being executed?

Comment: I think you need to show us the actual XPage with code or more parts of the code. There are several reasons backend code can start from CSJS.
One clue can be to have the developers tools activated and the network tab. to see all requests to the server and what starts it.

Comment: As soon as you call the addCallback function, the SSJS code (that you assigned to the corresponding remote procedure) is executed. What else should the RPC do? IMO you should be more specific in describing the problem you have...